# Lock Screen Dialer App Replaced with Microphone

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow

I have a OnePlus 2, although I suspect this applies to any Android 5.x OS. When I upgraded to Android 6.0, the dialer icon on the lock screen was replaced with a microphone (some sort of Google search thing).

I checked all the settings, but I can't seem to find any way to customize or change this to replace it with the dialer. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer [here](http://forums.androidcentral.com/android-6-0-marshmallow/592989-lock-screen-dialer-shortcut-gone-6-0-a.html):

> - Go to Settings > Apps
> - Click the Gear Icon (top-right of the UI)
> - Click on Default Apps > Assist & Voice Input > Assist app.
> - Click "None" (the other option is Google App).
>
> This puts the dialer shortcut back on the lock screen, but it also disables long-pressing the home button to launch the Google App.

Answer (score 0):

In CyanogenMod 13 (Marshmallow) you can can goto `Lockscreen` in Settings.

1. Inside that, select `Lock screen shortcuts`.
2. Tap on microphone(on the left), which displays `Choose action`, tap on `select application`. And, it displays `select custom app`, in that, select `Apps` and select activity `Phone`.